# InflateException android studio

Tags: android, view

I trying to make an APP, until then , all right, but I got an exception and I am unable to resolve it.

It happens every time I press the update button from my app:

[image: This button]

And I cath this error :/

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.codedream.controledereifeiao, PID: 831
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:128)
  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:121)
  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1280)
  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
  at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1170)
  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1075)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

This is the log, and my code:

```
package com.codedream.controledereifeiao;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.zxing.integrator.android.IntentIntegrator;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class main extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
        lisPessoa.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        lisRefeicao.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    ListView list;

    TextView uid;
    TextView name1;
    TextView telefone;
    Button Btngetdata;

    //URL to get JSON Array
    private static String urlJSON = "http://192.168.25.129/controlerefeicao/class/lis_pessoa_json.php";

    //JSON Node Names
    private static final String TAG_JSON_OBJ = "pessoa";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "nome";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_TELEFONE = "telefone";
    private static final String TAG_QRCODE = "qrcode";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    JSONArray pessoa = null;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewPeo);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        Fragment fragment = null;
        boolean fragmentSelected = false;

        if (id == R.id.nav_peo) {
            fragment = new lisPessoa();
            fragmentSelected = true;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_ref) {
            fragment = new lisRefeicao();
            fragmentSelected = true;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_con) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ha implementar",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (fragmentSelected) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                    .commit();

            item.setChecked(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(item.getTitle());
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public void criarPessoa(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CriarPessoa.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void criarRefeicao(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CriarRefeicao.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void carregarLista(View view){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Carregando lista",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new JSONParse().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewNomeItem);
            telefone = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTelItem);

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(urlJSON);
            return json;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            try {
                // Getting JSON Array from URL
                pessoa = json.getJSONArray(TAG_JSON_OBJ);
                for(int i = 0; i < pessoa.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = pessoa.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String telefone = c.getString(TAG_TELEFONE);

                    // Adding value HashMap key => value

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_TELEFONE, telefone);

                    oslist.add(map);
                    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewPeo);

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), oslist,
                            R.layout.fragment_lis_pessoa,
                            new String[] { TAG_ID,TAG_NAME, TAG_TELEFONE }, new int[] {
                            R.id.textViewIDPeoLis,R.id.textViewNomeItem, R.id.textViewTelItem});

                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                int position, long id) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Clicked at "+oslist.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

This is my Item Layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.codedream.controledereifeiao.lis_peo_item">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/textViewNomeItem"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/textViewTelItem"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewNomeItem"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/textViewIDPeoLis"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

And this is my ListView XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.codedream.controledereifeiao.lisPessoa">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listViewPeo"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/addPeoBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:onClick="criarPessoa"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/attPeoBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_popup_sync"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
    android:onClick="carregarLista"/>
```

This is my logcat

```
07-31 21:13:15.307: D/AudioFlinger(1231): mixer(0xb4580000) throttle end: 

throttle time(121)
07-31 21:13:16.743: D/AndroidRuntime(30317): Shutting down VM
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317): Process: com.codedream.controledereifeiao, PID: 30317
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class <unknown>
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:128)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:121)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1280)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1170)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1075)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
07-31 21:13:16.744: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-31 21:13:16.745: W/ActivityManager(1597):   Force finishing activity com.codedream.controledereifeiao/.main
07-31 21:13:16.795: I/OpenGLRenderer(1597): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
```

Please someone help me D:

Comment: Can you post your xml, I am saying this according to your logcat .

Comment: which android version you are using